# Is use case depending on another use case anti pattern?

Tags: clean-architecture

I have 2 use cases `LoadA` and `LoadSettings`, in `LoadA` I need to access the `Settings` returned from `LoadSettings`. The business is designed so that if `Settings` is not yet exist then a default `Setting` would be returned.

The default initialization logic is put inside `LoadSettings`, but now the `LoadA` must depend on the `LoadSettings` instead of calling the `SettingsRepository`, thus creating a **peer-dependency**.

Is this anti-pattern in term of strictly following Clean Architecture?

Comment: Possible duplicate
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40458666/the-clean-architecture-usecase-dependencies

Comment: Thanks for link! It's a duplicate even there is no accepted answer in the other question. And I don't think the only answer there is correct in my case!

Answer (score 5):

There have already been multiple answers to the question "May interactors call other interactors?" here on stackoverflow.

My favorite one is this [Clean Architecture: Combining Interactors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43803666/clean-architecture-combining-interactors) (Answer by Ben Neill) and I also follow it in my own projects.

Comment: Do you mean this link http://www.plainionist.net/Implementing-Clean-Architecture-UseCases/ ?

Comment: No I wanted to refer to the answer by Ben Neill. Sorry for being too unspecified. I updated my answer